# Need PCS_AAD_APPID and more to run Azure IoT storage-adapter microserver locally

Tags: azure-storage, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying the Azure IoT Accelerators Remote Monitoring solution and trying to follow the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-remote-monitoring-create-simulated-device

In it, I need to run the storage adapter microservice locally and for that to work, it seems that I need three environmental variables WHICH I DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIND THE VALUES FOR:

PCS_AAD_APPID = { Azure service principal id }
PCS_AAD_APPSECRET = { Azure service principal secret }
PCS_KEYVAULT_NAME = { Name of Key Vault resource that stores settings and configuration }

I can create those environmental variables but I have no idea what values I should put in there. Anyone?

FYI, right now when I'm running the storage adapter microservice locally, I get this error:

"{"Name":"StorageAdapter","Status":{"IsHealthy":false,"Message":"Storage check failed"}..."

...which is preceeded by a caught exception with this messae:

"AuthKey = '((Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient)this.client).AuthKey' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'"

Comment: Apparently there is a script that creates resources needed for tihs sample application and also generates and sets those variables please read this for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-remote-monitoring-deploy-local#deploy-the-azure-services  also if you start clean the tutorial you are following and can confirm that it doesn't work. You might want to open an issue so it gets fixed

Comment: Hi did you give that tutorial a shot? Did it work?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?